# openCV Number of contours is double expected?

Tags: opencv, contour

I'm new to openCV and this has been confusing me. I have an image that I tolerance to find a certain color (in this case green). I then pass it through canny and then findcontours. This all works except the number of contours is always double what I was expecting. For example if in my thresholded image I see 3 blobs I will get 6 contours, 4 blobs will be 8 contours. Why?

Here is my thresholded image:
[image: Thresholded image]

Here is my original image with a bounding rectangle and center point drawn for each contour
[image: bounded contours]

Its performing as expected except why are there always 2x the number of contours?

Here is my contour call for reference:

```
 /// Detect edges using canny
  Canny( imgThresholded, canny_output, canny_min, canny_min*2 );
  /// Find contours
  findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

UPDATE:
Here is the middlepoint and area of each contour it finds. Its essentially doubling up on each contour

```
1 - New finger centerpoint: 460.053 , 153.751 area : 1133
2 - New finger centerpoint: 460.108 , 153.739 area : 1101
3 - New finger centerpoint: 389.901 , 128.729 area : 1406.5
4 - New finger centerpoint: 389.899 , 128.776 area : 1367.5
5 - New finger centerpoint: 310.9 , 90.155 area : 1048.5
6 - New finger centerpoint: 310.872 , 90.1272 area : 1018.5
7 - New finger centerpoint: 224.2 , 84.9257 area : 1211
8 - New finger centerpoint: 224.156 , 84.9134 area : 1178
```

UPDATE2:

Here is the cannyoutput
[image: cannyoutput]

Comment: try to draw the contours, then you might see where the false contours are occuring. How to draw contours can be sen here:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

Comment: Drawing the contours gives the same result. I only see the expected 4 so I believe its doubling up on contours. The box's and dots you see are the bounding contour box and center points. IF there were stray ones I'd see random dots/box's on the image

Comment: create a new image for each contour and display them separately (a new window for each one or a `cv::waitKey(0)` between single displays) to be sure about that.

Comment: and try `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` instead of `CV_RETR_TREE`. maybe there's a "inner contour" and an "outer contour" for each blob or sth.

Comment: can you post/add your `Canny` result?

Comment: Updated with canny output and contour information

Comment: if you do canny, you will get an *outer* and a *inner* contour. try a simple `threshold(img,img,128,255,0);`instead. also:  CV_RETR_EXTERNAL

Comment: your canny image looks like as if there aren't closed contours but one blob is divided in 2 parts, giving you something like 2 half circles (with some pixel missing) instead of 1 circle. Try to adjust the canny thresholds to get full circle contours! Or it's really a inner/outer contour problem if the canny contours are connected. Try `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` mode